# Unable to create WHERE clause to update

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a WHERE clause that only allow 1 hour before NOW() TO 4 hours after NOW() and between 7am to 8pm. The attribute I am trying to update is date_time TIME type.

```
UPDATE lot
SET userid = 'UID00001', 
    lot_status = 'reserved', 
    date_time = '2017-11-20 19:30:00'
WHERE carparkid = 'CID00001' 
  AND lot_num = 1 
  AND lot_status = 'empty' 
  AND (date_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
                     AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR) 
       OR (DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%k:%i:%s') BETWEEN '07:00:00' 
                                                  AND '20:00:00')
      );
```

I tried many other ways but still cannot insert in my tuple. I inserted according my current time.

My current timing is 10:48

```
MariaDB [carparkful]> UPDATE lot
    -> SET userid = 'UID00001', lot_status = 'reserved', date_time = '2017-11-21 10:30:00'
    -> WHERE carparkid = 'CID00001' AND lot_num = 1 AND lot_status = 'empty' AND (date_time BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR)
    -> OR (DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%k:%i:%s') BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '20:00:00'));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [carparkful]> UPDATE lot
    -> SET userid = 'UID00001', lot_status = 'reserved', date_time = '2017-11-21 10:30:00'
    -> WHERE carparkid = 'CID00001' AND lot_num = 1 AND lot_status = 'empty' AND (date_time BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR)
    -> AND (DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%k:%i:%s') BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '20:00:00'));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

CREATE TABLE lot
(carparkid VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, userid VARCHAR(10), lot_num INT(3) NOT NULL, lot_status ENUM('empty', 'reserved', 'occupied') DEFAULT 'empty', date_time DATETIME);

MariaDB [carparkful]> select*from lot;
+-----------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+
| carparkid | userid | lot_num | lot_status | date_time |
+-----------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+
| CID00001  | NULL   |       1 | empty      | NULL      |
| CID00001  | NULL   |       2 | empty      | NULL      |
| CID00001  | NULL   |       3 | empty      | NULL      |
| CID00001  | NULL   |       4 | empty      | NULL      |
| CID00001  | NULL   |       5 | empty      | NULL      |
| CID00002  | NULL   |       1 | empty      | NULL      |
| CID00002  | NULL   |       2 | empty      | NULL      |
| CID00002  | NULL   |       3 | empty      | NULL      |
| CID00002  | NULL   |       4 | empty      | NULL      |
| CID00002  | NULL   |       5 | empty      | NULL      |
| CID00003  | NULL   |       1 | empty      | NULL      |
| CID00003  | NULL   |       2 | empty      | NULL      |
| CID00003  | NULL   |       3 | empty      | NULL      |
| CID00003  | NULL   |       4 | empty      | NULL      |
| CID00003  | NULL   |       5 | empty      | NULL      |
.........
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why doesnt work? any error message? wrong rows update? In your question you say between -1 and +4 and between 7am 8pm but you use `OR` in your query? otherwise your query seem to match your question request

Comment: Using an UPDATE to insert as claimed in the question is at least mildly confusing.

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%k:%i:%s')` checks the time for **any date**, is that really want you want?

Comment: i want it to work on anyday but can insert only timing from 7am to 8pm and 1hr before current time to 4 hrs after current time.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I tried both or and and do not work

Comment: Again you didnt explain what is wrong with your query now

Comment: As u see none of my update is able to update the date_time attribute